# Issue with .NET String.Split

Tags: c#, text, datagridview

I'm attempting to parse a text file containing data that is being used on a remote FTP server. The data is delimited by an equals sign (=) and I'm attempting to load each row in to two columns in a DataGridView. The code I have written works fine except for when an equals character is thrown into the second column's value. When this happens, regardless of specifying the maximum count as being 2. I'd prefer not to change the delimiter if possible.

Here is the code that is being problematic:

```
        dataGrid_FileContents.Rows.Clear();

        char delimiter = '=';

        StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader(fileLocation);

        String fileData = fileReader.ReadToEnd();
        String[] rows = fileData.Split("\n".ToCharArray());

        for(int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
        {
            String str = rows[i];

            String[] items = str.Split(new char[] { delimiter }, 1, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            if (items.Length == 2)
            {
                dataGrid_FileContents.Rows.Add(items[0], items[1]);
            }
        }

        fileReader.Close();
```

And an example of the file being loaded:

```
boats=123
cats=234-f
cars==1
```

It works as intended for the first two rows and then ignores the last row as it ends up creating a String[] with 1 element and two String[]s with zero elements.

Comment: You are adding the row only if the array contains two elements but it can never be longer than 1 since you use the overload of [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131450(v=vs.110).aspx). `String[] items = str.Split(new char[] { delimiter }, 1, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`. Use the standard `string.Split` without `count` argument and it should work.

Comment: What is expected value for "cars" - `=1` or `1`?

Comment: I need the second string completely intact (=1)

Comment: FYI, it's ".NET String.Split", not "C# String.Split".

Answer (score 0):

A different solution, if you want everything after the first equals then you could approach this problem using string.IndexOf

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
{
    String str = rows[i];
    int pos = str.IndexOf(delimiter);
    if (pos != -1)
    {
        string first = str.Substring(0, pos-1);
        string second = str.Substring(pos + 1);
        dataGrid_FileContents.Rows.Add(first, second);
    }
}
```

Comment: This results in the value associated with cars losing the leading equals sign.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. It will capture the value before and after the first '=', correctly parsing the `cars==1` scenario.

```
String[] items = str.Split(new char[] { delimiter }, 2, stringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just read all items delimeted by '=' in row.
Then iterate over items, and check, that item not empty, than use this prepared data to write

here illustrated snippet 
http://dotnetfiddle.net/msVho2

and your snippet can be transformed to something like bellow

```
dataGrid_FileContents.Rows.Clear();

char delimiter = '=';

using(StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader(fileLocation))
{
    string[] data = new string[2];

    while(true)
    {
        string row = fileReader.ReadLine();
        if(row == null)
            break;

        string[] items = row.Split(delimiter);
        int data_index = 0;
        foreach(string item in items)
        {
            if(data_index >= data.Length)
            {
                //TODO: log warning
                break;
            }

            if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item))
            {
                data[data_index++] = item;
            }

        }

        if(data_index < data.Length)
        {
            //TODO: log error, only 1 item in row
            continue;
        }


        dataGrid_FileContents.Rows.Add(data[0], data[1]);

    }
}
```